# Couchbase Client Failure

Tags: docker, couchbase

I´m trying to get/insert, any document with Couchbase but I get error from server response:

Couchbase.IO.ResponseStatus.ClientFailure

> A request has been made for a service that is not configured or
>   supported by the cluster. Please check the cluster and enable or add a
>   new node with the requested service: Data.

The couchbase server was installed under [oficial docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/couchbase/)

I have two nodes to avoid failover warning message and my app uses [The official .NET SDK for Couchbase Server](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CouchbaseNetClient/)

How to fix this error?

Comment: Well, did you enable the data service on the node you're connecting to?

Comment: How I can enable that? Tks.

Comment: Either when you create the bucket or the cluster or add nodes, cant remember, there's three checkboxes for data, index, and query

Comment: I saw this option when creating/add node. But the three checkboxes are checked.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. I'm just reading the error message... "Please check the cluster and enable or add a new node with the requested service: Data"

Comment: How are you opening your cluster connection and bucket? Have you tried specifying the bucket name when calling `OpenBucket`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try couple of things:
1) Make sure when you specify the cluster URL, you have /pools as the path. Example:

```
config.Servers = new List<Uri>
{
    new Uri("http://10.10.10.10:8091/pools")
};
```

2) Try removing the
    cluster.Authenticate(...)
line if you have it in your code. It may be configured where it may not need it but if you specify it you may get this error.